# Generating Excel and sending the sheet via Email in JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp

I currently got an assignment at work.

I am a Computer Science student and work part time at a call center. Our salary is calculated in excel sheets in how many hours we've worked from the 15th this month to the 15th the next month. Currently we have to fill our these excel sheets ourselves which is prune to errors.

I would like to be able to simply press a button on our schedule manager (which is written in JSP I am told) which then makes an excel sheet for me by pulling information from our schedule manager database, attach it to an email and send it to me.

Now, my question is if anyone had experience with these Java Excel libraries in a JSP environment?

I found two which I haven't tried yet but seem decent:

- [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

I'll figure out that Email part later.

Comment: My opinion is that JExcel is the better choice.

Comment: @duffymo What do you base this on?

Comment: @Top-coder Some basis for your claim please? :P

Comment: Like I said - my opinion, based on personal experience with both.  It's far more reliable than the nothing on which you based your 'decent' assessment.

Comment: @duffymo I looked over the documentation and examples, which is what I based my "decent assessment". No need to get rude :)

Comment: "Looked over" - right.  So why are you here?

Comment: @duffymo looks can deceive.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is schedule manager database.
1) Find its login information (from JSP source if it is server based or try hacking if schedule manager has its local client)
2) Build the script on any platform (I prefer local ftp)

Comment: I did that to all my workplace databases (mostly MsSql and Oracle) and increased work productivity by more than 500% using php local scripts.